# Is encryption less resistant to brute-forcing compared to hashing?

Tags: encryption, hash, brute-force

I understand that a hashing algorithm like bcrypt uses several rounds of hashing to make it computationally expensive for a brute-force attack. How does encryption work against a brute-force attack? I was wondering if a stolen encrypted file such as one encrypted with GnuPG can be cracked much much faster than a bcrypt hash of the same password assuming it is 10 char long using A-Za-z0-9!~?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To encrypt a piece of data, you need an encryption *key*. An encryption key has to be a long, random string. Passwords do not fit this criteria. So if you want to use a password as an encryption key, you need to use a [key derivation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function). Strong password hashing algorithms like `pbkdf2`, `bcrypt` and `scrypt` *are* key derivation functions.

So to answer your question, it depends. It depends on which KDF the application is using to stretch the password into an encryption key. GnuPG does use a KDF function (controlled by the `--s2k-*` set of flags).

Comment: Technically, bcrypt is not a true KDF, but its output is sufficient large (192 bits) that it can be used for generating symmetric keys. Similarly, PBKDF2 is a KDF, but it can still be used for password _hashing_.